# Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 't.languages')

Tags: ios, react-native, multilingual

I am trying to build my react-native app in ios but getting following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException:
Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 't.languages')', 
reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 't.languages'),
```

I am using RNI18n module for Multilingual. I have imported module successfully but still getting this error. I am able to run app on debug mode which is working absolutely fine but now workin in archive or device

Comment: Where have you written code for multilingual? Can you post that code?

Comment: I18n.defaultLocale = 'ar';
I18n.locale = 'ar';
I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  ar
};
const currentLocale = I18n.currentLocale();
if(currentLocale == 'ar_SA'){
  I18n.defaultLocale = 'ar';
  I18n.locale = 'ar';
} else{
  I18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
  I18n.locale = 'en';
}
export const isRTL = currentLocale.indexOf('ar') === 0;
ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);
export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return I18n.t(name, params);
};
export const switchLanguage = (lang, component) => {
  I18n.locale = lang;
  component.forceUpdate();
};

Comment: are you using version 0.60.5 of react-native or later?